# Хранение логина в БД

Tags: база-данных, авторизация

Хочу посоветоваться.
Как лучше хранить логин в БД.
Очевидный вариант как есть: в виде строки.
Вытаскивать соответственно запросом с LIKE,
но после того как БД завелись два зверя
с похожими именами "User" и "user", возникла мысль:
А что если логин хранить в виде md5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея плохая. =) Потому что если что, вы не сможете извлечь никакую инфу для юзера, который забыл логин. Да и самому сложнее ориентироваться.

Вариант1(как у взрослых дядей):

```
login(as is, латиница)|password(hash+salt)|Display_name(любые допустимые символы)
Ключ - userId, int
```

Вариант2(для извращенцев):

```
login(он же display name)|password(hash+salt)|hash(login+password)
Ключ - как раз последнее поле.
```

Comment: @knes, а почему логин только в латинице?

Comment: Давно восстанавливали БД, где косорукий админ "поигрался" с юникодом при дампе и превратил все в 

    ?????????

? =)

Я этим занимаюсь довольно часто, благо таких знакомых "админов" много. С тех пор у меня правило: вся служебка только латиницей/цифрами. Русский/иные языки - только для UGC или словарей.

Answer (score 2):

> Вытаскивать соответственно запросом с
> LIKE

Это бред. При авторизации тоже `LIKE` юзается? Это кошмар!

```
'user'=$_POST['user']
```

никак не

```
'user' like %$_POST['user']%
```

Хранить в хеше? А смысл есть? Проще избавится от `LIKE`!

Comment: мог бы, поставил ещё одну галочку.

Comment: При авторизации тоже LIKE юзается? Это кошмар!// Особенно хорош второй вариант:
пишем $_POST['user']='' и логинимся с паролем 12345. Или любым другим таким же.

Comment: @knes это было для примера. нет же смысла писать проверки ради того чтобы просто показать на явную ошибку.